# jQuery Mobile with Marionette or Chaplin?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette

I've written several web-based applications using Backbone in the past, but now I'm starting a new mobile application with Backbone.js and jQuery Mobile. I'm looking at using [Marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette) or [Chaplin](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin) to help provide better structure, view management and memory management. Eventually this will be wrapped up using PhoneGap to be deployed an an enterprise app.

However, I cannot seem to find anything that would indicate either of these work well (or don't work) with jQuery Mobile. To get the most benefits from them, I know I'll have to disable jQuery Mobile's, which is fine. I've also seen some questions with issues about [require.js and JQM not working well together either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904433/jquery-mobile-require-js-and-backbone). So does anyone know if it's easy to use either of these Backbone frameworks to develop mobile site in a way that will play nicely with JQM? Or have another Backbone based framework that is designed specifically for use with JQM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best Backbone + JQM tutorial that I know of is http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/

Marionette should work fine - though it will be rather slow at the moment. I've run Marionette based web apps on my phone's browser and it runs... but I am also aware that it ran slowly. I'm working on performance improvements for the next release (v0.9) but that may be another week or two away, depending on how much time I have before my next contract starts.

Comment: Do you suggest people out there to use MarionetteJS (1.0.0-rc4) with JQuery Mobile without any performance impact? I know you made lot of improvements to MarionetteJS from your last comment 07\2012.

Comment: Derick, My application on mobile taking 4-5 seconds to switch between views, Working fine on desktop. Any performance tips???