# data-role not displaying only one page in jqm

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs

I'm having some problems getting jquery mobile to work properly. I'm using [the anatomy of a page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) and [this stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904433/jquery-mobile-require-js-and-backbone).

The output I'm expecting is for jqm to only show the contents of the first data-role in the code. However, what's actually happening is after jqm loads, it sets the view to the size of the browser window, but still shows the contents of the second data-role plus the words "loading" beneath it.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very simple. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using PhoneGap and RequireJS.

Here is the code:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
    <title>Student Picker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="test1">
        <a href="#test2">Goto Test2</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="test2">
        <a href="#test1">Goto Test1</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js`

```
require.config({

baseUrl: 'js',
paths: {

    'jquery': 'jquery',
    'jquery.mobile.config': 'jquery.mobile.config',
    'jquery.mobile': 'jquery.mobile',
    'app': 'app'
},
map: {

    '*': {'jquery': 'jquery-private'},
    'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
},
shim: {

    'jquery.mobile.config': ['jquery'],
    'jquery.mobile': ['jquery', 'jquery.mobile.config']
}
});

require(['jquery', 'app', 'jquery.mobile'], function(jq, app) {

jq(function() {

    //app.initialize();
});
});
```

`jquery.mobile.config`

```
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {

jq(document).on("mobileinit", function () {

    jq.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    jq.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    jq.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    jq.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
});
```

Picture of the output:

[image: Output]

The results are the same with or without the jqm config file. If you need any more information, please feel free to leave a comment :)

Comment: Seems issue with jquery file includes. There is no jQM css or js file.

Comment: Oh, is there something else that I need besides the `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js` file? At the moment I have that, renamed as jquery.mobile in the js folder.

Comment: jqm css file? Is that there, too?

Comment: I just added the css file and it now works. I'm really confused as to why the css file is necessary to get it to work. If you'd like to write a quick answer, I'll mark that as correct :) Thanks FlamePrincess!

Comment: Actually, it half works. The page only shows the "Goto Test2" link now, but the link doesn't change to the other page. Thanks though, progress is being made!

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: I don't get any errors when clicking the link, but these errors exist when the  page loads: `GET file:///C:/Users/wasd/Desktop/wasd/www/cordova_plugins.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND cordova.js:1296 ` and 
 `GET file://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery.js:4 ` and 
 `GET file:///C:/Users/wasd/Desktop/wasd/www/css/images/ajax-loader.gif net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery.js:4` I've also tried deploying it to my android phone to see if it only happens on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS file corresponding to the JQM file is missing in the code.

Add CSS file and it should work because "data-role" works as a CSS selector.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the css file as FlamePrincess pointed out, but the link itself still doesn't change to the other page. It seems to work if i add pagecontainer("change", "target") code manually. Does JQM not handle links like that automatically?

Comment: JQM handles links automatically out of the box, we need not add anything. Please refer a simple fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5L3jwg9g/)

Comment: Interesting. There must still be something wrong with my configuration with requirejs. Thanks.